# Move part of the filename to the front of the filename

Tags: windows, powershell, rename, batch-rename

I want to move a part of the filename to the front of the filename.
All my files have a delimiter `#` in them, such as: `2585#xxxxx#4157.pdf`.

Now I want to move the part after the last `#` to the second part of the file name, e.g.: `2585#4157#xxxxx.pdf`

How can I do that with powershell? I have not yet looked into any methods myself as I don't know what to search for.

Comment: Are you familiar with regex?

Comment: Hi Robert, I took the liberty to format your question. As you didn't indicate what you've tried already I assumed you didn't look into any methods yet. If that's not the case, could you please [edit] your question and include any (failed) attempts? That helps others in providing you with a useful answer.

Comment: Does it have to be powershell or can it also be a batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below script will do what you're looking for. It's written in a not so concise loop such that every step of the way is clear. There are more optimal ways to script this.

```
# Assumes this script is run in the directory with the pdf files
# First get all pdf files in the current directory
$all_files = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter '*.pdf'

# Loop over all files
foreach ($file in $all_files) {
    # Get the current (old) filename
    $old_name = $file.Name
    # Define a regex pattern (see below)
    $regex_pattern = '(.+)#(.+)#(.+)(\.pdf)'
    # Define a replacement pattern (see below)
    $replace_pattern = '$1#$3#$2$4'
    # Construct the new name
    $new_name = $old_name -replace $regex_pattern, $replace_pattern
    # Actually rename the file
    Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $new_name
}
```

#### Regex

[Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is an advanced way to search (and replace) text.

The search pattern can be broken down into the following parts:

```
(.+)      Match any character 1 or more times, store in the first group
#         Match the # symbol literally
(.+)      Match any character 1 or more times, store in the second group
#         Match the # symbol literally
(.+)      Match any character 1 or more times, store in the third group
(\.pdf)   Match a literal dot followed by the letters "pdf" and store in the fourth group
```

The replace pattern uses re-orders the stored parts from the search pattern:

```
$1  Take the content from the first group
#   Write a literal # symbol
$3  Take the content from the third group
#   Write a literal # symbol
$2  Take the content from the second group
$4  Take the content from the fourth group
```

Running this script renames the following files:

```
2585#xxxxx#4157.pdf
2d23#ab23-421d#40++057.pdf
2d23#abd#400057.pdf
```

into

```
2585#4157#xxxxx.pdf
2d23#40++057#ab23-421d.pdf
2d23#400057#abd.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks Saaru, for the solution

Answer (score 2):

As alternative without regex, you can do this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\where\the\files\are' -Filter '*#*#*.pdf' -File) | 
Rename-Item -NewName { 
    $first, $second, $third = $_.BaseName.Split("#")
    '{0}#{1}#{2}{3}' -f $first, $third, $second, $_.Extension
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but when I am using this Iam getting a error.                                        'At line:4 char:131 + ... st, $second, $third = $_.BaseName.Split("#") '{0}#{1}#{2}{3}' -f $fir ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Unexpected token ''{0}#{1}#{2}{3}'' in expression or statement. + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken – '

Comment: @Robert I cannot reproduce that error. Also, the message mentions position _char:131_, but the longest line in the code is only 61 characters long... Did you copy/paste the code correctly? Seems you have leftover stuff in your editor.

Comment: Thnxx now it works after a small adjustment